# Could rockets launched from the ground use wings in the stages?

Tags: rockets, artificial-satellite, engine-design, aerodynamics, stages

Could a slower or smaller rocket take advantage of lift if all the stages had wings?

Could the stages reduce splashdown impact forces by using a [spinning seedpod-like design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samara_(fruit)) (as shown in the image below)?

**Seed pods twirling to the ground**
[image: Video of seed pods twirling to the ground]
<sup>Source: Keith Blenman [blogpost](https://keithblenman.blogspot.com/2015/05/)</sup>

**SpaceX BFR**
[image: ![SpaceX BFR]
<sup>Source: SpaceX via [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFR_(rocket)#/media/File:BFR_in_flight_(cropped).png), public domain</sup>

**X-37B**
[image: X-37B cut-away drawing and photo]
<sup>Source: [xairforces.net](http://www.xairforces.net/newsd.asp?newsid=817&newst=7#.XCbNY7hhrwc)</sup>

**Baikal flyback booster with second stage**
The flyback wing is stowed above and parallel to the fuselage
[image: Baikal flyback booster with second stage]
<sup>Source: Russian Foundation for Advanced Studies (FPI) via [russianspaceweb](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/baikal.html)</sup>

After what point are wings not useful on the number of rocket stages, size or weight?

Comment: Kindly attribute all images and quotes.  Thanks!

Comment: X-37 is under a fairing during the atmospheric portion of ascent, getting no lift from its wings; it does a gliding reentry and landing like the space shuttle.

Comment: I believe that's the X-37's orbital module (propulsion, consumables, etc.).  It's odd that it would have wings too; I suspect the reason for having them (like much surrounding the X-37) is classified.  Also, can you _please_ provide image citations?

Comment: @AlexHajnal The X-37 is one piece, not separate modules; the forward surfaces are wings, the aft are a V-tail.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I stand corrected.

Comment: What is the use of a wing if the rocket goes straight upwards to get out of the denser atmosphere to avoid drag and dynamics loads due to hypersonic flight?

Comment: @Uwe The X-37 is reüsable.  It uses those wings to glide to a landing.

Comment: @AlexHajnal et al. [pics of X-37 after landing here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21423/12102) help illustrate that the two tail fins in the back (bottom in this view) are not coplanar, but are pointing towards us, or "out of the page" in this view. (my awkward way of saying "V-tail")

Comment: [RLV-TD had it's wings and V-tail exposed](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20727/12102) during this test launch, but I believe it will be launched inside a fairing in the future)

Comment: The first link from @uhoh also nicely illustrates the precautions one has to take around Hydrazine.

Comment: Von Braun's Mars ship was all about the wings: http://i.imgur.com/D67k1.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't all satellite-carrying rockets launched from airplanes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/why-arent-all-satellite-carrying-rockets-launched-from-airplanes)

Comment: @Hobbes IMO this question is not a duplicate. This question is about the pros and cons of using wings directly on rockets for aerodynamic reasons whereas that question is about using winged (implicitly non-rocket) planes as first stages and for logistical purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though it seems noöne has spun an entire rocket stage to slow it, something similar has been tried.  The long-defunct [Rotary Rocket](https://web.archive.org/web/20010202132800/http://www.rotaryrocket.com) company was developing the Roton™ reüsable single-stage-to-orbit launcher that would use helicopter-like blades to slow and land.  A bit more info on it can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_Rocket).

[image: Roton booster]
<sup>Alan Radecki via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Roton_(rocket)#/media/File:Rotaryrocket-061114-01-8.jpg), GFDL / CC BY-SA 3.0</sup>

Not present in the photo above, the rotor blades were attached to the dome at the top and folded flush against the fuselage during ascent.  Prior to reëntry the blades would fold back to a low-drag configuration.  After reëntry, the blades would move to a horizontal orientation and be spun up (I believe) using thrusters on the blade tips (the cap and blades would spin and the fuselage would stay stationary).  The craft would then fly as a helicopter (under autorotation) to a controlled landing.

There are some [much better images here](https://web.archive.org/web/20010302083240fw_/http://rotaryrocket.com:80/new/new.html) (under "Photo Gallery" and "Image Gallery") but they don't appear to be licensed for reüse.

Comment: Naïvely speaking, I would think that the diæresis above the `u` in the word _reüse_ doesn't help anybody pronounce it correctly and only reïnforces an impression that the poster may be a bit of a pretentious hypercorrectiïst™. But that's just a hypothesis...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Both forms are equally valid in English.  If feel that the diæresis (to use an alternate spelling) plays a useful role and thus I often use it.  I prefer to reserve hyphenation for certain compound words and the like.

Comment: It's not useful at all. "Reuse" is a completely normal English word, which nobody has any difficulty in parsing to mean "use again". The diaresis just looks strange and interrupts the flow while the reader thinks, "What's that doing there?" It's at best archaic and, these days, verging on plain wrong.

Comment: The "reüse" thing is pure distracting nonsense. See [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reuse), [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reuse), and [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reuse). You won't find a diaeresis anywhere. Similarly "reëntry."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And OED lists "re-use" as the only acceptable form.  Make of that what you will.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you'd like I'll take a photo, upload it, and post a link here.  I understand your opinion and you're certainly welcome to use any of the three spellings.  I prefer using a different one than you and I hope you'll respect that.  That said I will take your argument into consideration in future.

Comment: I fully support Alex's right to his diæreses. Yes, they look a bit affected; but that is surely his choice? I rather like them myself.

Comment: Maybe the diaereses is an Umlaut?

Comment: @takintoolong Same symbol, different use.  Basically, the former doesn't change the meaning of a word while the latter does.  For example, in English "coöperate" and "cooperate" mean the same thing.  In German though, the meaning (and pronunciation) changes.  For example, "schön" mean "beautiful" while "schon" means "already".

Comment: Alex is in good company.  The New Yorker's style guide dictates a diaerisis on the second of two *identical* vowels, when that vowel starts a new syllable.  So yes for reentry and reeducate, no for reuse.

Answer (score 14):

> Could a slower or smaller rocket take advantage of lift if all the stages had wings?

Wings on the first stage can be useful; the [Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(rocket)) air-launched rocket has wings on its first stage that provide some lift.

In most cases wings aren't worth using on orbital launchers; they add drag and weight that usually isn't compensated for by lift. Wings on upper stages are very unlikely to be beneficial.

Comment: If you look at it properly, the first stage of the Pegasus is the L1011, which has wings and flies back to land and be reused.  Likewise for the carrier aircraft of the (suborbital) Spaceship One and Two.

Comment: To elaborate: Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(rocket)#Launch_profile) the purpose of the wings and control surfaces on Pegasus is primarily attitude control. In addition, the first (rocket) stage is not recovered. From the linked article: "The 45-degree delta wing (of carbon composite construction and double-wedge airfoil) aids pitch-up and provides some lift. The tail fins provide steering for first-stage flight, as the Orion 50S motor does not have a thrust-vectoring nozzle."

Comment: Skylon (which, I know, is still just conceptual design) uses wings and air-breathing engines to get to Mach 5 or so with relatively llittle fuel. This is the only example I know where wings play an important role in ascent of a rocket concept.

Comment: Jet powered first stages / carrier aircraft are not *rockets*, and that's meaningful because a rocket booster doesn't really benefit from wings during boost, and rockets are a poor match for something that would.  Now if you put RATO bottles on your carrier aircraft to operate from a short field, then *technically*, but...

Comment: @ChrisStratton Rockets don't benefit much from wings because of their trajectories, not because they're rockets per se. Serious consideration has been given to using jet modules on the first stage of an otherwise conventional orbital launcher: https://yarchive.net/space/launchers/jet_first_stage.html

Comment: @RussellBorogove - rockets don't benefit from wings quite specifically *because they are rockets* because rockets loose more in trajectories that could benefit from wings than they gain from wing lift, and for trajectories that could benefit from wings, rockets are woefully inefficient compared to alternatives that work well there: air breathing jets - which again *are not rockets* even if present on a composite vehicle that also has rocket upper stages.

Answer (score 6):

Vertically launched rockets need thrust (force in the direction of motion), not lift (force perpendicular to it). Wings can only provide lift and drag (force against the direction of motion), and a vertically launched rocket needs neither of those things.  What an orbital rocket does need is speed so the less drag the better.

Comment: Just expanded your argument a bit.  Feel free to roll back if you like.

Comment: All this answer does for me is make me ponder the wisdom of a horizontally launched rocket, not convince me that wings are unwise. After all, wouldn't it be really great if our (horizontally-aimed) thruster could do double-duty of speeding us up to orbital speeds and giving us a source of lift to gain altitude at the same time?

Comment: @DanielWagner the point is, if you have a horizontal lanch it's in the atmosphere for a lot longer, which means more drag over time (and, to a much lesser extent, lift). The reason rockets launch out of the atmosphere straight up and gradually turn as they leave is to minimize the time spent in the atmosphere. By minimizing time spent in the atmosphere you're minimizing drag over time.

Comment: The point of this answer is that rockets are far inferior in efficiency to air-breathing jets are generating thrust at slow to moderate speeds for the extended period of time as a wing-lift climb to altitude requires.  If you are going to build a wing-lift booster, you give it jet engines and save the rockets for upper stages.  If you put wings on a vertical launch rocket booster, they're for recovery, not climb.

Comment: @DanielWagner But a rocket motor _already_ does double duty by directly giving altitude and speed gain.

Comment: vertically launched rockets don't remain vertical for long

Comment: @JCRM no, but they do spend a very considerable part of their fuel during the vertical ascent.

Answer (score 5):

The rocket passes through the dense layers of the atmosphere in the first tens of seconds after launch. Further, these wings are ineffective. Baikal (on render) is a reusable rocket plane. Most of the time being in dense layers of the atmosphere.

Comment: Yes like the lower rocket stages +1

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the goal is the Earth orbit (the outcome could be different for Mars), the kinetic energy in a low orbit is about 30 MJ/kg. There is little use to lift a rocket to the, say, 20 km level using air-breathing engines and wings in order to supply 0.2 MJ/kg of potential energy before starting the rocket motors.

Also the initial kinetic energy (e.g. 1 % for an initial speed of 10 % of the orbital speed) would not even compensate the extra structural weight necessary on the part of the rocket to accept and spread the lift force, which is orthogonal to the inertial force with rocket thrust. This aspect is less important for small rockets.

To minimize gravity drag (lost acceleration in vertical direction before reaching orbital speed), a rocket accelerates rapidly, thus spending only few seconds in any speed range wings could be designed for. This aspect is less important for manned rockets (limited acceleration).