# Super Capacitor Stages

Tags: launch, rockets, stages, design-alternative, electric-propulsion

Could this super capacitor be up scaled to be of use in the lower stages of a rocket?

Here is the only information I found online on this?

Related: [Could rockets launched from the ground use wings in the stages?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33152/could-rockets-launched-from-the-ground-use-wings-in-the-stages)

Comment: I think using propellors to launch to space has been ruled out in previous answers, as well as any electrical form of propulsion, but I'm not 100% sure. It is a fun video though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No

Even if overall design makes a helicopter lifted first stage sensible you still need good energy density (power per KG of energy storage). Super capacitors have a special properties that make them useful but energy density by [weight is not one of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density).

Going off the linked (and plausibly out of date) table they would need to be ten times better to equal basic Li-ion batteries and a thousand times better to equal jet fuel for a rotor lifted first stage.

One application that is worth watching for high density/high discharge rate electrical power is with turbo pumps, as [per Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(rocket)) where electric drive offers some advantages over the design complexity/cost inherent in combustion driven pumps.